# Application resilience impact using Logstash/Graylog log appender

Tags: java, logging, log4j, graylog2

I have some question about the gelf module (http://logging.paluch.biz/) and in particular when the graylog server is not available for some reason.

1. Is log4j will cache the logs somewhere and will send them when the connection to the graylog is recovered?
2. Is the application using this module will stop to work during the issue with graylog server?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Gelf-Appenders are online appenders without a cache. They connect directly do a remote service and submit log events as your application produces these.

If the remote service is down, log events get lost. There are a few options with different impacts:

1. **TCP**: TCP comes with transport reliability and requires a connection. If the remote service becomes slow/unresponsive, then your application gets affected, as soon as I/O buffer are saturated. `logstash-gelf` uses NIO in a non-blocking way if all data was sent. If the TCP connection drops, then you will run into connection timeouts, if the remote side is not reachable or connection refused states if the remote port is closed. In any case, you get reliability, but it will affect your application performance.
2. **UDP**: UDP has no connection notion, it's used for fire-and-forget communication. If the remote side becomes unhealthy, your application usually is not affected, but you encounter log event loss.
3. **Redis**: You can use Redis as an intermediate buffer if your Graylog instance is known to fail/been taken down for maintenance. Once Graylog is available again, it should catch up, and you prevent log event loss to some degree. If your Redis service becomes unhealthy, see Point 1.
4. **HTTP**: HTTP is another option that gives you a degree of flexibility. You can put your Graylog servers behind a load-balancer to improve availability and reduce the risk of failure. Log event loss is still possible.

If you want to ensure log continuity and reduce the probability of log event loss, then write logs to disk. It's still no 100% guarantee against loss (disk failure, disk full) but improves application performance. The log file (ideally some JSON-based format) can then be parsed and submitted to Graylog by maintaining a read offset to recover from a remote outage.